# Cannot find OpenCV module

Tags: python, opencv

When I try `import`ing `cv2` and running the code I get an error:

```
import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

even though I have used the `pip install opencv-python` in the command prompt.

I even used

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

in the command prompt to try updating opencv but I keep running into the same problem. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: You have two (or more) versions of Python installed on your computer.  `pip` installed the cv2 module for one version of Python, but you're using a different version of Python to run the code.

Comment: How, exactly, are you running the code?  Are you typing `python myscript.py` at the command line, or are you using an IDE such as VS Code, or some other way?

Comment: OpenCV is an external binary. Assuming you followed the installation docs [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/d65/tutorial_table_of_content_introduction.html), you may have to add an environment variable to your path.

Comment: @Jamie_D I don't believe a missing external binary would cause a simple import error.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm using pycharm to run the code

Comment: Then you must have pip and PyCharm configured to use different versions of Python.

Comment: I deleted all other versions of python and re-entered the command "pip install opencv-python" into the command prompt and installed opencv, but I still get the same error

Comment: You must still have two versions installed.  Show us the output of this command `pip --version` and this code in pycharm `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: Thank you for the help, I ended up installing opencv through pycharm, view>tool windows>python packages

Comment: this is how to install opencv:  `pip install opencv-python`